# migration from oracle procedure to postgresql function UTL_FIle

Tags: postgresql, utl-file

[image]

As shown in image i'm facing this issue . Please help me out as i'm new to postgresql.

Comment: https://github.com/orafce/orafce

Answer (score 0):

There are no packages in PostgreSQL, in particular there is no package `UTL_FILE`.

You'll have to modify your code and your table definition.

There are [file access functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-GENFILE) for reading data, the [adminpack](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/adminpack.html) contrib module has a function to write files, and you can use PL/Perl functions to access the file system.